# std::out_of_range what(): basic_string::substr

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program for an assignment, but whenever I run it, the program is terminated, saying:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' 
what(): basic_string::substr
```

Here is my code for the entire program:

```
//Jaime Rhoda! Program 6! Sleep deprivation!
//This program will read in a list of dates.
//It will then seperate the months, days, and years.
//It will print the dates in a variety of styles.

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ifstream input ("input.txt");
ofstream output ("output.txt");
string readoriginaldate ();
void breakoriginaldate (string, string&, string&, string&);
void printdate3ways (string,string,string);
int main() {
    output<<"This is Jaime! Welcome to program 6! I'm tired :(\n\n";
    while (input) {
        string month,day,year;
        string date=readoriginaldate();
        breakoriginaldate(date, month, day, year);
        printdate3ways(month,day,year);
    }
    return 0;
}
// This function takes no parameter.
//It reads in one character string from a file.
//It returns the string. Nice and simple.
string readoriginaldate() {
    string date;
    input>>date;
    return date;
}
//This function reads in a string (date).
//It seperates the string into 3 parts.
//It returns no value.
void breakoriginaldate (string date, string &day, string &month, string &year) {
    int pos=date.find('/');
    day=date.substr(0,pos-1);
    int pos2= date.find('/',pos+1);
    month=date.substr(pos+1,pos2-pos);
    year=date.substr(pos2,2);
    output<<date<<" is the original date.\n\n";
    output<<month<<" is the month \t"<<day<<" is the day.\t"<<year<<" is the year.\t\t";     
}
//This function takes the month, day, and year.
//It prints them the American way, and all the other ways.
//It returns no value, like a bad invesment!
void printdate3ways(string month,string day,string year) {
    string wordmonth;
    if (month=="1")
        wordmonth="January";
    if (month=="2")
        wordmonth="February";
    if (month=="3")
        wordmonth="March";
    if (month=="4")
        wordmonth="April";
    if (month=="5")
        wordmonth="May";
    if (month=="6")
        wordmonth="June";
    if (month=="7")
        wordmonth="July";
    if (month=="8")
        wordmonth="August";
    if (month=="9")
        wordmonth="September";
    if (month=="10")
        wordmonth="October";
    if (month=="11")
        wordmonth="November";
    if (month=="12")
        wordmonth="December";
    string fullmonth, fullday;
    if (day.length()<2)
        fullday='0'+day;
    else
        fullday=day;
    if (month.length()<2)
        fullmonth='0'+month;
    else
        fullmonth=month;

    string european=day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
    string american=wordmonth+""+day+", "+"20"+year;
    string full=fullmonth+'-'+fullday+'-'+"20"+year;
    output<<"The European way-> "<<european<<"\n\n";
    output<<"The American way-> "<<american<<"\n\n";
    output<<"The full way-----> "<<full<<"\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Try to understand what the exception is telling you: std::out_of_range identicates that you are accessing something which is not here; basic_string::substr tells you that this is in one of your calls to substring. So, start looking at those indices. Debugging is a good skill to have and helps you in the long run. When you've found your error you can write an answer to your post and explain what you did wrong. This further increases your learning experience.

Answer (score -1):

The error can occur if you incorrectly enter the data. As  you do not check the correct format then try to enter the date correctly. Also you extract fields of the data also incorrectly.

Try the following function definition

```
void breakoriginaldate ( const string &date, string &day, string &month, string &year ) 
{
   string::size_type pos = date.find( '/' );
   day = date.substr( 0, pos );
   string::size_type pos2 = date.find( '/', pos + 1 );
   month = date.substr( pos + 1, pos2 - pos - 1 );
   year = date.substr( pos2 + 1 );

   output << date << " is the original date.\n\n";
   output << month << " is the month \t"<<day << " is the day.\t" << year<<" is the year.\t\t";     
}
```